# Is an iOS App Store promo code usable by multiple people, or just one per code?

Tags: ios, app-store, promotion-code

Is it possible to generate a single promo code which can be used multiple times by multiple users, or is there a one-to-one mapping between codes and specific users?

What I'd like to do is publicly post a single code anyone can use.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promo codes are one use only.  The person using it is buying your app but without paying any money to Apple.  You could lower the price of your app to free for a limited time if you wanted.